# convert string 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' date to integer (pandas, python)

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I need to convert the difference between two strings with a format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, representing a `datetime`, into a `integer`. Since I want to to do this on all the index of a DataFrame object (built with pandas), I need a builtin function, to do something like

```
data['difference'] = somefunc(data['date1'],data['date2'])
```

Does such a function exist? If I build my own function, how can I apply it to the DataFrame columns?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check this link : http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=strptime
Basically you can parse a string into a struct_time variable and then access the values via the attributes (tm_hour, tm_min...).

Check the example for time.strptime.

Answer (score 0):

Requires numpy >= 1.7. This is for pandas 0.13 (releasing soon). See docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-deltas)

```
In [3]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = Timestamp('20130101'), B = Timestamp('20130101')+ pd.to_timedelta(list(range(5)),unit='D')))

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
                    A                   B
0 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-01 00:00:00
1 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-02 00:00:00
2 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-03 00:00:00
3 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-04 00:00:00
4 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-05 00:00:00

[5 rows x 2 columns]

In [5]: df.dtypes
Out[5]: 
A    datetime64[ns]
B    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

In [6]: df['C'] = df['B']-df['A']

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
                    A                   B                C
0 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-01 00:00:00         00:00:00
1 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-02 00:00:00 1 days, 00:00:00
2 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-03 00:00:00 2 days, 00:00:00
3 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-04 00:00:00 3 days, 00:00:00
4 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-05 00:00:00 4 days, 00:00:00

[5 rows x 3 columns]

In [8]: df.dtypes
Out[8]: 
A     datetime64[ns]
B     datetime64[ns]
C    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object

In [9]: df['C'].astype('timedelta64[s]')
Out[9]: 
0         0
1     86400
2    172800
3    259200
4    345600
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

In 0.12 you can do this

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = Timestamp('20130101'), B = [Timestamp('20130101')+timedelta(days=i) for i in range(5) ]))

In [2]: df['C'] = df['B']-df['A']

In [3]: Series(df['C'].values / np.timedelta64(1,'s'))
Out[3]: 
0         0
1     86400
2    172800
3    259200
4    345600
dtype: float64
```